# Is there a word for "seen from above"?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

I'm trying to find pictures of houses as they would be seen if looked directly down from a helicopter.

I tried "house from above", but it didn't bring me good results. Is there a better word for this?

Comment: I tried both *aerial* and *bird's-eye* in Google Images, and discovered the difference.  Aerial is farther away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normally referred to as an [*aerial*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/aerial_1) view; for example, [OpenAerialMap](https://openaerialmap.org/) is "The open collection of aerial imagery."

Comment: Another common expression for this is "bird's eye view".

Answer (score 6):

> **A bird's-eye view** is an elevated view of an object from above, with a perspective as though the observer were a bird, often used in the making of blueprints, floor plans, and maps.
>
> It can be an aerial photograph, but also a drawing. Before manned flight was common, the term "bird's eye" was used to distinguish views drawn from direct observation at high locations (for example a mountain or tower), from those constructed from an imagined (bird's) perspectives. Bird's eye views as a genre have existed since classical times. The last great flourishing of them was in the mid-to-late 19th century, when bird's eye view prints were popular in the United States and Europe.
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%27s-eye_view)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps. Arial viewni  good but less formal could be observed? Looking/ed down on/upon?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please don't write answers as questions. Be bold! Write a real answer (with justification). And please do proof-read and correct — it's still wrong.

Comment: You had a good idea, but you didn't didn't verify the spelling, which could also have yielded an authoritative definition to cite.  As a result, you suggested the name of a typeface, which is a wrong answer.  Also, this is an English language site, so using proper English, proofing for obvious typos, etc. is kind of important for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"overhead shot" is another term.

As for finding them, Google Earth is the ideal program.  It may be possible to use Google Maps and select "satellite view" and also get this view.